# firefox download file in the Download window - Firefox Extension!

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I have this function to download a file :

```
function downloadFile(httpLoc)
{
try {
    // new obj_URI object
    var obj_URI = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService).newURI(httpLoc, null, null);

    // new file object
    var obj_TargetFile = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);

    obj_TargetFile.initWithPath("d:\\te.zip");

    if(!obj_TargetFile.exists()) {
        obj_TargetFile.create(0x00,0644);
    }

    var obj_Persist = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/embedding/browser/nsWebBrowserPersist;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIWebBrowserPersist);



    obj_Persist.progressListener = {
        onProgressChange : function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aCurSelfProgress, aMaxSelfProgress, aCurTotalProgress, aMaxTotalProgress){
            var percentComplete = (aCurTotalProgress/aMaxTotalProgress)*100;
            var ele = document.getElementById("progress element");
            ele.innerHTML = percentComplete + "%";
        },
        onStateChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aStateFlags, aStatus) {
        }
    }

    // with persist flags
    const nsIWBP = Components.interfaces.nsIWebBrowserPersist;
    const flags = nsIWBP.PERSIST_FLAGS_REPLACE_EXISTING_FILES;
    obj_Persist.persistFlags = flags | nsIWBP.PERSIST_FLAGS_FROM_CACHE;

    //save file to target
    obj_Persist.saveURI(obj_URI, null, null, null, "", obj_TargetFile);
}
catch (e) 
{
    alert(e);
}
}
```

The file is downloading but i don't see it in the Firefox Download Window. How do i make the file to appear in the Download Window and see the progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/annotate/ccf0a112a858/toolkit/components/downloads/test/unit/head_download_manager.js#l103) should give you a good start on the right way to do this.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is [better to include the essential parts of the answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: @Makyen, I don't think those were the standards when I answered this five years ago :)  I also linked to a specific revision so it wouldn't be dead.

Comment: Yes, standards have changed over the years. However, current standards are applied retroactively in that old up-voted answers do get deleted if they are link-only. While I disagree with this, ([my post on meta that highly up-voted answers with dead links should have the links changed to archives](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323508/what-to-do-with-broken-but-highly-upvoted-link-only-answers/323562#323562)), reality is that such answers get deleted if they are flagged putting them in the low quality posts review queue. I did not flag this answer to give a chance for it to be updated.

Comment: To get deleted it does not take a majority of people feeling that way.  Just one person to flag the answer.  Then the people in the review queue to click on the prominent option of deleting because it is link only. Most reviewers, probably almost all, will quickly send such answers to deletion. I *think* this specific answer may be immune to that due to being accepted, but I am not sure.